# AVPlayerLayer/CALayer removeFromSuperlayer() leak

Tags: swift, macos, calayer, avplayerlayer

Inside my app I play a video via an AVPlayerLayer (CALayer). I have the following function for fading in a new video. It adds a new AVPlayerLayer and removes the old layer after the fade in animation happened.

```
import Cocoa
import AVFoundation

class FZPlayerView: NSView {
    private let mainLayer = CALayer()

    override public init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        commonInit()
    }

    required public init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: decoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        wantsLayer = true
        layer = mainLayer
       mainLayer.masksToBounds = false
    }


    func setPlayer(player: AVPlayer) {
            let newPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
            newPlayerLayer.player = player
            newPlayerLayer.player?.play()
            self.addAllObserversFor(player: newPlayerLayer.player!)
            mainLayer.addSublayer(newPlayerLayer)

            CATransaction.begin()
            let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
            animation.fromValue = 0.0
            animation.toValue = 1.0
            animation.duration = 0.1
            CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
                for sublayer in self.mainLayer.sublayers! {
                    if let avplayerSublayer = sublayer as? AVPlayerLayer {
                        if avplayerSublayer != newPlayerLayer {
                            self.removeAllObserversFor(player: avplayerSublayer.player)
                            avplayerSublayer.player?.pause()
                            avplayerSublayer.player = nil
                            avplayerSublayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            newPlayerLayer.add(animation, forKey: "opacity")
            CATransaction.commit()
    }

    func  removeAllObserversFor(player: AVPlayer?) {
        player?.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status")
        player?.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "timeControlStatus")
        player?.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "rate")
    }

    func addAllObserversFor(player: AVPlayer) {
            player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions(rawValue: 0), context: nil)
            player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "timeControlStatus", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions(rawValue: 0), context: nil)
            player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "rate", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem, queue: .main) { [unowned player] _ in
            player.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
            player.play()
            }
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        //for future code
    }

}
```

```
import Cocoa
import AVKit
class ViewController: NSViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var playerView: FZPlayerView!

   @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: NSButton) {
       guard let contentUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "01 Cozy", withExtension: "mp4") else { return }
       let player = AVPlayer(url: contentUrl)
       playerView.setPlayer(player: player)
   }

   override var representedObject: Any? {
       didSet {
       // Update the view, if already loaded.
       }
   }

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
   }

}
```

For some reason this function causes a memory leak. Why? I'm removing the old AVPlayer and layer.

Comment: What memory leak does it cause? How do you know? Is the problem a retain cycle? If so, did you try saying `[unowned self] in` at the start of the completion block? Thanks.

Comment: Also could you please show enough code to allow this to be reproduced? What is `player`? What is `self.addAllObserversFor` etc.? Thanks

Comment: @matt Thanks. I added the missing code. `[unowned self] in` seems to help mostly but the memory still seems to grow slightly after each `setPlayer()`  call. I'm watching the memory via Xcode's memory report.

Comment: I don't even know under what class you are writing those lines of code.

Comment: @Flocked Okay rule one, Xcode's memory gauge is not a real measurement of anything. It is just an estimate, plus memory management running from Xcode on the Simulator in Debug mode is not the same as real memory management! You should use this purely as a sign that it might be a good idea to switch to Instruments and _really_ measure. So do that. You will then be able to see whether anything is actually leaking over the long term and, if so, what it is. Until then, you don't actually have any evidence of a leak.

Comment: @matt Okay. Thanks for the tipp. I will use instruments. - I btw. added the full code.

Comment: Cool, let me know what you find on Instruments! Use the memory allocation plus leaks tool, exercise the app, and see what happens.